# RHEL upload / pull scripts from people without access to the server itseld

Tags: rhel, python

I have a RHEL Server and would like to enable a group of users to be able to upload / modify mostly Python script that enrich data in our ticketing system. The problem is that they can't have access to the shell and I don't want to go each and every time to make the corrections / uploads for them ? What alternative could I possibly have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put it in a git repository, and have the server periodically pull from a git repository (either host your own or put it on github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc.). Then you can grant the individuals rights to commit and push changes to the scripts.

Comment: Thank you! Got no experience with it but sounds promising. Do you have maybe a tutorial on that ?

Comment: Lots of suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414140/git-auto-pull-using-cronjob